# How to created a new object through nested routes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So, following is the way I have defined the routes for my application:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :operators do
       resources :cabs
  end
end
```

As understood, my app has a few cab operators and each operator has a certain number of cabs associated with them:

```
class Operator < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cabs
end
```

The problem comes when I am trying to create a new cab, as:

```
<%= link_to 'New Cab', new_operator_cab_path %>
```

The new cab creation form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @cab, url: operator_cabs_path, method: :post do |f| %>
                  <% if @cab.errors.any? %>
                    <div id="error_explanation">
                      <h2><%= pluralize(@cab.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this cab from being saved:</h2>

                      <ul>
                      <% @cab.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                        <li><%= message %></li>
                      <% end %>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  <% end %>

                  <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :category %><br>
                    <%= f.text_field :category %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :number %><br>
                    <%= f.text_field :number %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="actions">
                    <%= f.submit %>
                  </div>
                <% end %>
```

I had to explicitly define the url and the method in the form as the default url (cabs_path) wouldnt exist according to the way the routes have been defined. 
Though my links are working fine, but no new cab gets created. Following is my cabs_controller:

```
class CabsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cab, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /cabs
  # GET /cabs.json
  def index
    @cabs = Operator.find(params[:operator_id]).cabs
  end

  # GET /cabs/1
  # GET /cabs/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /cabs/new
  def new
    @cab = Cab.new
    @operator = Operator.find(params[:operator_id])
  end

  # GET /cabs/1/edit
  def edit
    @operators = Operator.all
  end

  # POST /cabs
  # POST /cabs.json
  def create
    @cab = Cab.new(cab_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @cab.save
        format.html { redirect_to operator_cabs_path, notice: 'Cab was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cab }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @cab.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /cabs/1
  # PATCH/PUT /cabs/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cab.update(cab_params)
        format.html { redirect_to operator_cabs_path(operator_id: @operator.id), notice: 'Cab was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @cab }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @cab.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /cabs/1
  # DELETE /cabs/1.json
  def destroy
    @cab.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to operator_cabs_path(operator_id: @operator.id), notice: 'Cab was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_cab
      @cab = Cab.find(params[:id])
      @operator = Operator.find(params[:operator_id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def cab_params
      params.require(:cab).permit(:category, :number)
    end
end
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to use something like @operator.cabs.build_cab(cab_params)  If you want the operator to 'have' the cab.  Reference Chris' answer for the needed associations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few questions and pointers:

- Does your Cab model include `belongs_to :operator`, as well as an `operator_id` column of type integer?
- Your `new_operator_cab_path` needs to be told which operator the cab belongs to, like this: `new_operator_cab_path(@operator)`.
- The same problem as above exists in your form URL: `@cab, url: operator_cabs_path`. In this case, you can simply fix it by replacing it with `[@cab.operator, @cab]`, which Rails will translate to the appropriate URL.
- Since this is a nested resource, you'll want to build your new cabs a little differently. Instead of `Cab.new` in your **new** and **create** actions, you'll want to use `Operator.find(params[:operator_id]).cabs.build`. This will specifically build a cab belonging to your operator.

Here are some related resources you may find useful:

- [Rails Association Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)
- [Rails Routing: Creating Paths and URLs from Objects](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects)